# How to use tinymce with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, tinymce

I am totally new to CakePHP.
I want Tinymce editor in my webpage.

I have followed the link: [Using TinyMCE with CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jtreglos/2006/09/23/using-tinymce-with-cakephp)

As per this link I have added JavaScript helper in my AppController file but it shows an error: "Helper class javascriptHelper could not be found."

Also confused that where to place this code:

```
<?php if(isset($javascript)): 
     echo $javascript->link('tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'); 
endif; ?>
```

I am using CakePHP 2.9.3 & TinyMCE 4.0.6
can anyone help me by specifying the step to configure TinyMCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the publish date of that article you linked? :)

You can use this [plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE) for CakePHP 2.x.

Comment: i have downloaded the plugin & followed the steps. it generates the script in page source tinymce.init({
theme : "advanced",
mode : "textareas"
}); but does not show the textarea. plz help